# How to access other table field in create trigger?

Tags: mysql

I have two table that relationship. member and setting. setting foreign key to member with member_id field. the question i want to access field in setting. i want to trigger event when member already delete it will chain to delete everything in setting.

> Member table -> member_id int
>
> Setting table -> member_id int

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pandora`.`member_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `member`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM `setting` WHERE OLD.member_id = @member_id;
    END;
```

Comment: You don't need to use a trigger. Define the foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, i can use ON. but i want to use CREATE TRIGGER. but i fix it already.

Comment: If you have fixed it please publish as an answer so that others may benefit from your experience or delete to limit clutter..